Pass Table as Parameter Error: No mapping exists from object type to a known managed provider native type
The requiremt is to pass a table as a TableType parameter to a SQL StoredProcedure from Power BI. Unfortunatly I get the following error:

No mapping exists from object type
Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Common.DataReaderDbDataReader to a
known managed provider native type.

My working TSQL is:
DECLARE @TableVariable AS _TT_DSGVO

INSERT INTO @TableVariable
      ([Firma]
      ,[Vorname]
      ,[Nachname])

    SELECT top 10 * FROM [_Datenanalyse].[dbo].[_T_DSGVO]

EXEC  _Datenanalyse.dbo._P_Refresh_DSGVO @TableVariable

_TT_DSGVO is a customed TableType and _P_Refresh_DSGVO is my StoredProcedure that for now should only read the data passed to it.
Inspired by the YouTube video "Calling a StoredProcedure from Power BI" by Guy in a Cube I tried the following setup in the Advanced Editor:
let
    Source = Sql.Database("srv04.serv.org", "_Datenanalyse"),
     NativeQuery = Value.NativeQuery(Source, 
                        "DECLARE @TableVariable AS _TT_DSGVO
                        INSERT INTO @TableVariable  
                        ([Firma]
                        ,[Vorname]
                        ,[Nachname])
                        
                        SELECT top 10 * FROM [_Datenanalyse].[dbo].[_T_DSGVO]
                        
                        EXEC  dbo._P_Refresh_DSGVO @TableVariable", [TableVariable = DSGVO], [EnableFolding=true])
in
    NativeQuery

The DSGVO in [TableVariable = DSGVO] is a table form a second DataSource that I need to pass to the stored procedure. But like I said the error above does not let me do it as I wish.
Please help me pass the TableType Variable correctly via Advanced Editor.
